# Oracle XMLQuery with namespace

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-namespaces

I have a Oracle Table with a varchar column. The content of this column are XML Strings.
Now I try to extract the value of a Tag Attribute of this column.
This works fine until the XML content has a defined namespace.

The following code works fine:

```
with testTable(xml_val) as (select xmltype('   
    <InstanceName>          
        <PromotionInstance>       
        <Cycle> 
            <Type>
                <TypeValue days="28"/>                      
                </Type>
            </Cycle>
        </PromotionInstance>
    </InstanceName>
    ') from dual)
select xmlcast(xmlquery('/InstanceName/PromotionInstance/Cycle/Type/TypeValue/@days' passing xml_val returning content) as number(2)) as days from testTable;
```

But this code returns always "null":

```
with testTable(xml_val) as (select xmltype('   
    <InstanceName xmlns="foobar">          
        <PromotionInstance>       
        <Cycle> 
            <Type>
                <TypeValue days="28"/>                      
                </Type>
            </Cycle>
        </PromotionInstance>
    </InstanceName>
    ') from dual)
select xmlcast(xmlquery('/InstanceName/PromotionInstance/Cycle/Type/TypeValue/@days' passing xml_val returning content) as number(2)) as days from testTable;
```

So I've tried to find a solution. I've found out, that I have to declare the namespace in the XMLQuery. But how?

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a default namespace with:

```
select
  xmlcast(
    xmlquery(
      'declare default element namespace "foobar";
      /InstanceName/PromotionInstance/Cycle/Type/TypeValue/@days'
      passing xml_val
      returning content
    )
    as number(2)
  ) as days
from testTable;
```

Or use XMLTable:

```
select x.days
from testTable t
cross apply xmltable (
  xmlnamespaces(default 'foobar'),
  '/InstanceName/PromotionInstance/Cycle/Type/TypeValue'
  passing t.xml_val
  columns days number(2) path '@days'
) x;
```

which is more flexible, and simpler if you want to extract multiple things from the XML at once.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=29d37bc806e1aae9b1342029ab9d598a)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps.
One more question:
What i have to to, if I have the XML Declaraion in the first line of the XML Text.
    .
Then I get the following Error:

ORA-31011: XML-Parsing nicht erfolgreich
ORA-19213: Fehler bei XML-Verarbeitung in Zeilen  2
LPX-00209: PI-Namen, die mit XML beginnen sind reserviert
ORA-06512: in "SYS.XMLTYPE", Zeile 310
ORA-06512: in Zeile 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.

Comment: @Jürgen - you don't have to do anything if it is actually the first line; but if you've (for aesthetic reasons, say) added a line break *before* it then it will get that error; it has to really be the first line, so immediately after the opening quote. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9bca51617f6caf46a624662756f879d9)

Comment: Oh yes I see. Thats exactliy what I have done. THanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XMLTABLE`:

```
with testTable(xml_val) as (
select xmltype('   
    <InstanceName xmlns="foobar">          
        <PromotionInstance>       
        <Cycle> 
            <Type>
                <TypeValue days="28"/>                      
                </Type>
            </Cycle>
        </PromotionInstance>
    </InstanceName>
    ') from dual
)
select days
from   testTable t
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
           XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'foobar'),
           '/InstanceName/PromotionInstance/Cycle/Type/TypeValue'
           passing t.xml_val
           COLUMNS
             days NUMBER(2) PATH './@days'
       );
```

Which outputs:

> | DAYS |
> | --- |
> | 28 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=48c0e88763466981bebc66b7a41040ba)*